# Rescue - NoMethodError -- undefined method log for brassring class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mechanize, resque

I am trying hard to send the below code as a background job, while bumping into one or another error in time to time,

my app/workers/brassring.rb is

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__)+"/base_parser"
class Brassring < BaseParser
@queue = :Brassring_queue
 def self.perform(page)
super page
   .............
end
   site_done

rescue Exception => e
def self.perform
log "error: #{e}"
end

end
end
```

and my app/workers/base_parser.rb is

```
#require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'mechanize/form'


class BaseParser


def initialize(site)
......
end


def add_fields_to_form(form, fields)
.....
end


def run
.................

end




def html2text(data)
......
 end


def save_result_page(url, result_params)
 ............
 end

def get_fields_from_page(page)
.......
    end

def set_site_status(status)
........
end


def update_run_counter
.......
end

def site_done
......
end


def log(what)
.....
end

def utf8(untrusted_string)
.......
end
```

I am queuing this using Rescue_enqueue method in my lib/brassring.rb as

```
Resque.enqueue(Brassring,@site_id)
```

when I try to run the job using   rake resque:work QUEUE=* 
It is failing by in my rescue control panel

NoMethodError
Error:
undefined method `log' for Brassring:Class
/home/my/to/sorc/app/workers/brassring.rb:39:in`rescue in perform'
/home/my/to/sorc/app/workers/brassring.rb:5:in `perform'

or what should I do to get it work.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: you haven't shown line 39 from /app/workers/brassring.rb:39 in your code, please add it.

Comment: also, you seem to have two `self.perform` methods in brassring.rb

Comment: log "error: #{e}" this is line 39 as this is my first question in stack overflow I dont know how to add line numbers :)

Comment: yes I think we need to add each method a perform  right?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're misunderstanding how the `rescue` statement works in Ruby.  You need to start with a `begin`, and then put a `rescue` statement at the bottom of your `begin` statement to close it out, dictating what should be done if/when the code errors out.  I would recommend you read a guide outlining how exceptions and rescuing works within ruby [such as this one](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html).

Comment: Sorry I was not talking about the ruby exceptions , rather on resque jobs(background jobs)